# Oncreate()is called after setResult instead of OnActivityForResult() in 2.2.1 LG-P500

Tags: android

In my application I use the `startActivityForResult()` and get the result using `SetResult` (request code,data). It is working fine, but in LG devices the `setResult()` is not getting called directly. First it is calling the `onCreate()` and then calling the `onActivitForResult()`

Below is my code

```
FirstActivity Button Click event 

startActivityForResult(new Intent(TestActivity.this, Details.class),1);
```

call the onactivity result of first activity in second activity using below code

```
Intent data=new Intent();
                data.putExtra("TEST", true);
                setResult(2, data);

                Details.this.finish();
```

Give me some suggestions for this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure u are not finishing the calling activity.......

Answer (score 0):

it was crazy. I spend much for solving this issue and as result following fixed this issue:

turn off "Developer options" -> Apps -> "Don`t keep activities" option